# How to add a new spreadsheet with VBA-Code, using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a macro and part of the macros function is to make VBA create a new spreadsheet. Because of the nature of distribution the name will change. I need to add code to this spreadsheet. Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jook has already explained how it works. I will take it a step further.

The syntax of adding a worksheet is

```
expression.Add(Before, After, Count, Type)
```

If you check inbuilt Excel's help then you can see what `Before`, `After`, `Count`, `Type` stands for

**FROM EXCEL"S HELP**

**Parameters** (*All 4 parameters are Optional*)

1. `Before` - An object that specifies the sheet before which the new sheet is added.
2. `After`  - An object that specifies the sheet after which the new sheet is added.
3. `Count`  - The number of sheets to be added. The default value is one.
4. `Type`   - Specifies the sheet type. Can be one of the following XlSheetType constants: `xlWorksheet`, `xlChart`, `xlExcel4MacroSheet`, or `xlExcel4IntlMacroSheet`. If you are inserting a sheet based on an existing template, specify the path to the template. The default value is xlWorksheet.

Once the sheet is created then you need to use `.insertlines` to create the relevant procedure and to also embed the code that you want to run.

**NOTE - IMP**: If you want the code to embed code in the VBA project, you need to ensure that you have "*Trust Access to the VBA Project Object Model*" selected. See snapshot.

[image]

Here is an example where I am creating a sheet and then embedding a `Worksheet_SelectionChange` Code which will display a message "Hello World"

**CODE - TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nLines As Long
    Dim VBP As Object, VBC As Object, CM As Object
    Dim strProcName As String

    Set ws = Worksheets.Add

    Set VBP = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBC = VBP.VBComponents(ws.Name)
    Set CM = VBC.CodeModule

    strProcName = "Worksheet_SelectionChange"

    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents( _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ws.Name).CodeName).CodeModule
        .InsertLines Line:=.CreateEventProc("SelectionChange", "Worksheet") + 1, _
        String:=vbCrLf & _
        "    Msgbox ""Hello World!"""
    End With
End Sub
```

This is how the new sheet code area looks once you run the above code.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

the following code will add you a spreadsheet.

```
Public Sub Workbook_Add()
 Dim wks As Worksheet
 Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(, , 1, xlWorksheet)
 With wks
   'set codename of wks
   ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(.CodeName).Name = "tblWhatever"
   'set tablename of wks
   .Name = "whatever"
   'add code (untested demo)
   'ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(.CodeName).CodeModule.InsertLines 1, "Option Explicit"
   'add code (as of example from excel-help)
   'Application.VBE.CodePanes(1).CodeModule.InsertLines 1, "Option Explicit"
 End With
End Sub
```

If you need to add VBA-Code to this specific spreadsheet, you should further inspect the VBProject object - look for *CodeModule* and then i.e. *InsertLines*.

A further hint for you - I would try to use the CodeNames of your tables. It is less likely to be changed - BUT it might be not that comfortable to use in your code at first. I had to get used to it, but for me it has many advantages against using a tables name.

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

The default `.Add` method adds a sheet at the start of the list.  Often you want to add it *at the end* before adding the code lines, as explained by [Siddarth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140579/siddharth-rout). To do that anywhere you can use:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.ADD  After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
```

It is easier to read if you have defined and set WB:

```
  Dim WB as Excel.workbook
  Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
      WB.Sheets.ADD  After:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count)
      Set VBC = ActiveSheet     'If using in Siddarth Rout's code above
```

`Sheets` and `Worksheets` are interchangeable, as illustrated.