# Batch add a macro to word documents?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have several hundred .doc word documents to which I need to add a macro which runs when the .doc file is opened and creates a header for said document based on the file name. Is there a way to do this as a batch? I have been individually opening each document and going into visual basic --> Project --> This Document then inserting a .txt file which contains the code. Is there a fast way to do this for multiple documents?

Comment: do you have any experience in vba? can you open>>save>>close .doc files (several hundred) using vba? what version of MS-Office you are running?

Comment: how many lines are there in your text file? does it start with `Private Sub Document_Open()`??

Comment: I have limited experience using VBA, most of which involves recording actions from word and running them. I am not familiar with much of the actual language. The text file does start with Private Sub Document_Open() after a couple lines such as delimiter and image paths. The full document is 812 lines long.

Comment: It's feasible to do what you need with vba code but it's not so easy especially if you have limited experience of VBA. You need to explore possibilities of writing VBA code by other VBA code. This could be [good starting point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278372/how-to-add-a-new-spreadsheet-with-vba-code-using-vba/12280837#12280837). Than you need to process this code for all files you want (search for `Dir function` in VBA). Finally you will need to read you text file and write it to `Sub Document_open()`- for that search for `Open statement` and `Line Input # statement` in vba help.

Comment: This question is similar to yours (it's for Excel not Word) but should be more than enough to get you going. If you have any problems after adapting it you can then post some code to help.

Answer (score 1):

As a learning exercise, put this into the "ThisDocument" part of Normal (the Normal.dot template) in the VBE

Open a word document and watch what happens.

I don't think you need to put your code in every single file, I think you should be OK with using the Document_Open event in Normal.dot.

Just make sure it shows up as a reference in your word documents that you open but I don't see why it wouldn't

If you absolutely need it in every file then it can be done but the problem is if you make one small change to the code, you have to go through  all this again. The idea with code is to write it once, use it many times.

Answer (score 0):

You can write VBA code that alters the VBA code in other documents, but you need to "Trust access to the VBA project object model" in the Trust Centre options. This could open you up to viral code if you download Word documents with malicious VBA code in them. What you want to do, essentially, is write a VBA virus. There are legitimate reasons for doing this, and also malicious ones, I leave the ethics of the uses of these techniques up to the user. Knowledge itself is not malicious.

Here's the meat, you will need to write your own code to loop through the documents and possibly save them as .docm files.

```
Sub ReplaceCode()

Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
Set oComponents = oDoc.VBProject.VBComponents

For i = oComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
    If oComponents(i).Type = 100 And oComponents(i).Name = "ThisDocument" Then
        With oComponents(i).CodeModule
            .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
            .AddFromFile "C:\ThisDocument.cls"
        End With
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Also, if you create your code file by exporting from VBA, you will need to remove this from the top of the .cls file:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
```

Personally, I would drive this from Excel, maybe using a worksheet to hold a list of the files or locations to update, and another sheet for the code to populate with a list of files updated.